# objects of objects? or maybe nested objects? in javascript

Tags: javascript, nested

I would like to be able to fill an array by calling something like.

```
necessaryLevel('a','b').necessaryLevel2('name',[X,Y,Z])
```

The the following as a possibility,

```
necessaryLevel('a','b').necessaryLevel2('name',[X,Y,Z]).option(5)
```

I also need that .option() can only be access from necessaryLevel2, that is, within the context of the code it should not be possible to write,

```
necessaryLevel('a','b').option(5)
```

I'm fairly new to javascript, and am just starting to learn about objects and inheritance. Also is nested the correct term here?

Any pointers (no pun intended)?

Example:

```
tag('a','nameVal').value('function_name',[funarg1,funarg2])
```

output:

```
['a','nameVal','function_name',[funarg1,funarg2]]
```

if .option is added I might get something like

```
tag('a','nameVal').value('function_name',[funarg1,funarg2]).option(2)
```

output:

```
['a','nameVal','function_name1',[funarg11,funarg21],'function_name2',[funarg12,funarg22]]
```

Edit:

Playing around a little bit I have this (not finished):

```
function foo(x){
     return {
          bar:function(y){return [x,y] };
      }
 }

 > foo(9.9).bar('la')
 [ 9.9, 'la' ]
```

What I'm having trouble with is added an option function so that I can repeat what goes into the bar(),
example:

```
 > foo(9.9).bar('la').option(4)
 [ 9.9, 'la', 'la', 'la', 'la' ]
```

and still have the flexibility to type foo(9.9).bar('la')

Comment: `necessaryLevel()` and `necessaryLevel2()` are functions, just so you know. Also, I don't understand your question. *Fill an array*, what array?

Comment: What are the `...` in your output?

Comment: The ... are "other".  I will take them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

## Example

```
var tag = ( function ( hier ) {

  var array = [];

  var calls = [];


  var repeater = function () {

    return function ( times ) {

      while ( calls.length < times ) {

        hier[1].apply( this, calls.slice( -1 )[0] );

      }
      // for


      return array;

    };

  };


  var adder = function ( child_name, child, repeat ) {

    return function () {

      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 0 );

      var orig_args = [].concat( args );

      if ( repeat ) {

        args[0] += calls.length + 1;

        calls.push( orig_args );

      }


      array = array.concat( args );


      var return_val = [].concat( array );


      if ( child_name !== undefined ) {

        return_val[ child_name ] = child;

      }


      return return_val;

    };

  };


  var last_child, args;

  hier.reverse().forEach( function ( child, index, hier ) {

    var method = index ? adder : repeater;

    args = last_child || [];

    if ( index === 1 ) {

      args.push( true );

    }


    hier[ index ] = method.apply( this, args );

    last_child = [ child, hier[ index ] ];

  } );


  return hier.pop();

} )( [ 'tag', 'value', 'option' ] );
```

In this version, the array itself is returned, but if you don't want to overwrite native properties or methods of `Array`, you have to be careful with naming your properties (e.g. `value`, `option`).

## JS object model

> Also is nested the correct term here?

Kind of.  In JS, functions are first class objects, which means you can pass them to functions, return them, assign them to properties of objects, etc.  You're asking to have a function `tag` that returns an object with a `value` property, which is a function, that returns an object with an `option` property, which is a function.

If you just had nested objects, the hierarchy would look like the following.  The `{...}` is object literal syntax for instantiating a new, generic object, which are used in place of hashes / maps / dictionaries in JavaScript and are unordered.

```
var tag = {

  value : {

    option : {}

  }

};
```

So for example, you'd be able to access `option` like:

```
tag.value.option
```

You're asking for a hierarchy of functions that each returns an object with a function as a property.  So in that case, to get to `option`, you'd have to do this:

```
tag().value().option
```

And in this case, `option` is a function, not a generic object.

## JS function expressions

> What is it called when you do `var a = (function(heir){...})(['a','b','c'])` with the parathesis?

One name it's been given is "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)" (see below).

The following is a function expression.  It creates a function object, which you could pass to a function, save in a variable or object property, etc.

```
function ( hier ) {...}
```

You can also execute a function expression in-place without assigning it to anything:

```
( function ( hier ) {...} )( ['a','b','c'] )
```

That executes the function expression.  You can of course assign the return value if you want:

```
var whatever = ( function ( hier ) {...} )( ['a','b','c'] );
```

There are a couple of reasons for the parens around the function expression.

1. The difference between a function statement and a function expression in JavaScript can be subtle.  To invoke the function in-place like this, it must be an expression, and the parens are one way of ensuring that it is.  Here are examples of others:

   Prefix it with an operator:

   ```
   +function ( hier ) {...}( ['a','b','c'] )
   ```

   Put it on the right hand side of an assignment:

   ```
   var whatever = function ( hier ) {...}( ['a','b','c'] );
   ```
2. Even when it's assured that it will be evaluated as an expression, as in the last example, some people think it's a good convention to use the parens anyway to make it more obvious that the return value of the function, and not the function itself, is the value of the expression (in this case the value being assigned to the variable).

There's a good article on the topic: [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), by Ben Alman, who suggests calling this construct by that name (IIFE).

Comment: the full call is "tag('a','nameVal').value('function_name',[funarg1,funarg2]).option(2)".  So the option repeats what goes into the array, at the same time it labels the elements. The value of 2 passed into option(2) determines the number of repeats.

Comment: Ok, I added an updated example that performs the repetition. It labels the "function_name" part, and you could have it label the arguments somehow as well.

Comment: Thanks! What is it called when you do "var a = (function(heir){...})(['a','b','c'])" with the parathesis?

Comment: I updated the post to answer your question, see "JS function expressions".